# Validar/Convertir texto en UTF8 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, utf-8

Tengo que generar una serie de xml recuperando información de una base de datos. La empresa que procesará los xml requiere que solo se empleen caracteres UTF8 pero en la información que recupero de la base de datos existen multitud de carácteres no permitidos como acentos, ñ, ...

```
Dim b As String = "AaáÁäÄñÑ"
Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(b)
Dim a As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
```

Esto me devuelve como caracteres "no extraños" solo la "a" y la "A".

He buscado información sobre los carácteres permitidos en UTF8 pero he visto diferentes tablas y no se muy bien de cual fiarme.

Había pensado es en hacer una sustitución de las vocales acentuadas por no acentuadas, las ñ por n, ... pero no se si habría una solución mas efectiva.

¿Hay alguna manera de optimizar esta tarea?
¿Como puedo obtener la lista de caracteres permitidos en UTF8?

Comment: UTF8 permite caracteres acentuados,ñ,etc...[Aqui](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) tienes una lista de caracteres aceptados

Comment: Creo que estás algo *liaillo*, o que no te expresas con claridad. La `ñ`, los caracteres con acentos `áéíóú` **son caracteres `UTF-8`**. `UTF-8` es una *codificación*, y no tiene nada que ver con las *grafías*.

Comment: De hecho estaba por contestar pero creo que la pregunta en si no es suficiente para elaborar una respuesta ya que como dijeron los compañeros, no deberías tener problemas con esos caracteres. Si los que procesen los XML precisan que la codificación sea UTF-8, pues utilizar Ñ y demás acentos es parte de esa codificación.

Comment: Pues entonces hay algo que se me escapa. Edito mi pregunta para añadir código.

Comment: Claro, por que utilizas `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes` .Prueba con `Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b)`

Comment: @Pikoh ponlo como respuesta :-)

Comment: @Pikoh Si que funciona así muchas gracias. Se me habia _colado_ esa parte del código. Fallo tonto.

Comment: De nada Jaime. A todos se nos escapan cosas de vez en cuando ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF8 permite caracteres acentuados,ñ,etc... En [Complete Character List for UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) tienes una lista de caracteres aceptados.

El problema con tu código de prueba es que para obtener los bytes usas la codificación por defecto  con `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes`. Tienes que utilizar la codificación UTF-8. Asi quedaría tu codigo de prueba:

```
Dim b As String = "AaáÁäÄñÑ"
Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b)
Dim a As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
```

---

Aprovecho para recomendar una página (en inglés) que explica perfectamente todo el tema de Unicode y codificación de caracteres: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: y aprovechando.. ¿Que pasaría si hubiera un carácter no permitido? ¿Lo transformaría?

Comment: Pues me has pillado, ya que nunca me ha ocurrido, pero en principio creo que lo sustituiría por una `?`  Segun la documentación de [Encoding.UTF8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx) `Devuelve un objeto UTF8Encoding que usa la reserva de reemplazo para reemplazar cada cadena que no se puede codificar y cada byte que no se puede descodificar con un signo de interrogación ("?")` De todas maneras yo no me preocuparía,es muy raro que encuentres un caracter no codificable en UTF8

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh.

Comment: Por cierto, recomiendo mucho que leas este articulo (en ingles lamentablemente) que explica perfectamente todos estos temas [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)